# Custom DataContract Serializer

Tags: c#

```
public class InfoSerializer : IInfoSerializer
{
    private static readonly ILogger _logger = LoggerFactory.Instance.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            var writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo)).WriteObject(writer, info);
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    public BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
    {
        var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BackgroundJobInfo));
        using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(info, XmlNodeType.Document, new XmlParserContext(null, null, null, XmlSpace.None)))
        {
            try
            {
                var result = (BackgroundJobInfo)dataContractSerializer.ReadObject(xmlTextReader);

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // hopefully, will never happen
                _logger.ErrorException(e, "Error when deserializing a BackgroundJobInfo object from string <{0}>", info);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it good serializer? Maybe I can improve it or I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. In `Deserialize()` you swallow all types of exception.  Catching and swallowing all exceptions is generally considered to be a bad practice.  In fact, Microsoft has a compiler "design warning" for this: [`CA1031: Do not catch general exception types`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx).  Instead, you should swallow exceptions that you might reasonably expect, and rethrow the rest.  E.g. if you were deserializing from a file, then it would be reasonable to catch and handle `FileNotFoundException`.

   Swallowing all exceptions can mask future problems in the code.  For instance, if somebody were to modify `BackgroundJobInfo` and add a property whose type is [not supported by the data contract serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or change the order of pre-existing properties thereby invalidating old XML (`DataContractSerializer` is [order sensitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) then the resulting bug might not be immediately noticed.

   For more, see [Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx) and/or [Is catching general exceptions really a bad thing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164256/is-catching-general-exceptions-really-a-bad-thing).
2. [`XmlTextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XmlTextWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are both deprecated as of .Net 2.0.  Microsoft suggests using [`XmlReader.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`XmlWriter.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.
3. Your methods to serialize and deserialize XML from a string using `DataContractSerializer` look handy, and could usefully be made generic for reuse later.

Thus:

```
public class InfoSerializer : IInfoSerializer
{
    private static readonly ILogger _logger = LoggerFactory.Instance.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
    {
        return DataContractSerializerExtensions.SerializeXml(info, null); // If you want indentation, use new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = "    " };
    }

    public BackgroundJobInfo Deserialize(string info)
    {
        try
        {
            return DataContractSerializerExtensions.DeserializeXml<BackgroundJobInfo>(info);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // hopefully, will never happen
            _logger.ErrorException(e, "Error when deserializing a BackgroundJobInfo object from string <{0}>", info);
            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static class DataContractSerializerExtensions
{
    public static string SerializeXml(this object obj, XmlWriterSettings settings = null)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
                serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);
            }
            return textWriter.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static T DeserializeXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        if (xml == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xml");
        using (var textReader = new StringReader(xml))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(textReader))
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)serializer.ReadObject(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

If you are using [`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and wish to suppress the serialization of specific properties, you should apply [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733811%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specifically [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the type and [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to each member to be serialized.  Note that data contracts are opt-in so once you start to use data contract attributes, all members of a type to be serialized must be marked as data members.  For instance:

```
[DataContract]
public class BackgroundJobInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    public string JobName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int JobPriority { get; set; }

    // Not marked with DataMember so not serialized.
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

See [Using Data Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As for creating a single static `DataContractSerializer` to be shared globally, I don't recommend it since there might be issues with threading.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **Thread Safety**
>
> Instances of this class are thread safe except when the instance is used with an implementation of the IDataContractSurrogate or DataContractResolver.

Unless you have determined via profiling that you have performance issues due to excessive allocations, it would appear safer to not share this class between threads.

Throwing an exception trying to serialize a property with `"password"` in the name is not implemented out of the box with `DataContractSerializer`.  You should be able to adapt the `XmlWriter` from [Custom xmlWriter to skip a certain element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32149676/custom-xmlwriter-to-skip-a-certain-element/32150990), then throw an exception rather than skipping the element.

Comment: About exceptions. Since http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms573849.aspx says nothing about possible exception types, I have to catch all

Comment: I have one question, I don't want to serialize everything. I would like to create a custom attribute "DoNotSerializeAttribute".

If some property in `obj` contain that attribute then ignore it and do not serialize and if some property contains "password" in the name and do not contain this attribute then generate exception. How can I do this?

Comment: Is it good way to create private static readonly DataContractSerializer instead of local variable? How to do that correctly?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko - answer updated.

Comment: I need `DataMember` marker. If I will not have it I will broke my functionality(write to register and RESTful-calls)

Comment: @dbs That's why I said about creating custom attribute

Comment: Can you show how to use IDataContractSurrogate to solve my problem( I don't want to serialize everything.) ?

Comment: @dbs Also you need to call `Flush()` after `serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, obj);`

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko - 1) it's not necessary to call `xmlWriter.Flush()` because the `XmlWriter` does this automatically when closed and disposed via the `using` statement.  Or did you encounter a bug?  2) You asked *Can you show how to use IDataContractSurrogate to solve my problem( I don't want to serialize everything.) ?*  I'd suggest asking a second question about that, possibly on stackoverflow.  Code review is for peer reviews of completed code.

Comment: Yes, I have a bug, without `xmlWriter.Flush()` I have empty string